# Design Model Survey?

Tags: rup

I am trying to do a Design Model Survey, however im am unsure what it includes. I have tried googling, and found the Term 4+1. the 4+1 does not correlate dirctly to the Softare Architecture Artifact

Does anyone have any good examples of the design model, or a tutorial or on how to do it, or even a list of what it should contain with a good description?

- RUP = Rational Unified Process
- UP = Unified Process

Many thanks (and i applogise for my wording)

bones

Comment: I've never heard of "Design Model Survey", or of "rup" or "up", come to that. Perhaps you could make it a bit clearer what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I just googled it and the first hit that came back looks pretty promising.
http://www.rhjconsulting.com/rationalunifiedprocess/process/artifact/ar_desmd.htm

There's also a specific link on that page to design model survey:
http://www.rhjconsulting.com/rationalunifiedprocess/process/reports/re_desms.htm

Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, i have seen these. thanks, however it really did not detail, weather or not to have the Process View, Implementation View and the Deployment view. if you follow the RUP examples on the website, they do not have an example of this being used

Comment: @dbones - I see your point. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.